# The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid. please give me ans how to solve this?

Tags: query

```
2018-09-12T11:10:10+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => mH0beURMu1wxCcyr
                            [Password] => pJmnsSlbrXspInt6PnxMpERmL
                        )

                )

            [ClientDetail] => Array
                (
                    [AccountNumber] => 510087640
                    [MeterNumber] => 119059115
                )

            [Version] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

            [RequestedShipment] => Array
                (
                    [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2018-09-12T11:10:07+00:00
                    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                    [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Amount] => 700
                            [Currency] => INR
                        )

                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 395010
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                )

                        )

                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                    [Residential] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => 510087640
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomsValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 700
                                    [Currency] => INR
                                )

                        )

                    [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                    [PackageCount] => 1
                    [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                    [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 2
                                            [Units] => KG
                                        )

                                    [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                    [InsuredValue] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Amount] => 700
                                            [Currency] => INR
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [xml_request] => 
    [xml_response] => 
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
            [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Severity] => ERROR
                    [Source] => crs
                    [Code] => 521
                    [Message] => Destination postal code missing or invalid. 
                    [LocalizedMessage] => Destination postal code missing or invalid. 
                )

            [Version] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

        )

    [__pid] => 8972
)

2018-09-12T11:14:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => mH0beURMu1wxCcyr
                            [Password] => pJmnsSlbrXspInt6PnxMpERmL
                        )

                )

            [ClientDetail] => Array
                (
                    [AccountNumber] => 510087640
                    [MeterNumber] => 119059115
                )

            [Version] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

            [RequestedShipment] => Array
                (
                    [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2018-09-12T11:14:18+00:00
                    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                    [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Amount] => 1598
                            [Currency] => INR
                        )

                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 395010
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                )

                        )

                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 201301
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                    [Residential] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => 510087640
                                    [CountryCode] => IN
                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomsValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 1598
                                    [Currency] => INR
                                )

                        )

                    [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                    [PackageCount] => 1
                    [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                    [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 4
                                            [Units] => KG
                                        )

                                    [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                    [InsuredValue] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Amount] => 1598
                                            [Currency] => INR
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [xml_request] => 
    [xml_response] => 
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
            [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Severity] => ERROR
                    [Source] => crs
                    [Code] => 691
                    [Message] => The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.
                    [LocalizedMessage] => The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.
                )

            [Version] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

        )

    [__pid] => 8972
)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? what are you planning to, and what version of magento is this? Magento 1 or Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue of fedex you need to modify "**vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php**"
 by adding

```
'CommercialInvoice' => ['Purpose' => 'SOLD'],
```

Search for "CustomsClearanceDetail" and add above line Just after "CustomValue" index you found this at two locations.